# .htaccess Error 404

Tags: php, html

Bien tengo un dominio y cuando se genera un error 404 mi htaccess no me redirecciona al archivo que tengo para dicho error

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

cabe destacar que mi 404.php esta dentro de la carpeta public_html

Answer (score -1):

Has probado añadir a tu archivo `htaccess` el modo `RewriteEngine on` que no veo en tu ejemplo, es decir, es un módulo provisto por el servidor Apache que permite crear URLs alternativas a las URLs dinámicas generadas por nuestras aplicaciones web.

**Ejemplo htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 / 404.php
```

**Nota**: te dejo una alternativa más avanzada, con unos ejemplos practicos.

Fuente OSes:

[¿Como hago el .htaccess para el 404?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39837/como-hago-el-htaccess-para-el-404/39846#39846)