# ¿Cómo redireccionar página error con php?

Tags: php

Estoy utilizando un ejemplo que encontré en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39837/como-hago-el-htaccess-para-el-404/39846#39846) la idea es redireccionar al no existir una página pero sin utilizar `.htaccess`

El problema en este **script** de **php** es que toda página correcta es direccionada a la página de `/error/`

Existe forma de detectar una página no existente con **php** y redireccionar a la página de error sin utilizar `.htaccess`

```
<?php
   $error_url = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"] . '/';
   $error_path = $error_url . '.php';

   if ( ! file_exists($error_path)) {
      // this is the default error if a specific error page is not found
      $error_url = '404/';
   }

   header('Location: ' . $error_url);
   exit;
?>
```

Comment: Se puede verificar si una página existe tal cual estás haciendo. Pero, ¿cómo vas a ejecutar el script si usuario está accediendo a una página que no existe? ... ¿Cuál es el objetivo de todo esto?   ¿Por qué no usar `.htaccess`? ¿Por qué no definir una página de error 404 personalizada directamente?

Comment: @Mariano Tienes toda la razón amigo entonces es necesario utilizar `.htaccess` pero como lo haría de esta forma he observado que en otros sitios web si escribes mal la **Urls** de esta manera: `example.com/refrefef` no es dirrecionado muestra el mensaje de error de una plantilla personalizada del mensaje de error 404 pero permanece en la misma **Urls** `example.com/refrefef` sin redirrecionar a otra **Urls** cómo podría implementar esa misma acción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> entonces es necesario utilizar `.htaccess` pero como lo haría de esta
>   forma he observado que en otros sitios web si escribes mal la **Urls**
>   de esta manera: `example.com/refrefef` no es dirrecionado muestra el
>   mensaje de error de una plantilla personalizada del mensaje de error
>   404 pero permanece en la misma **Urls** `example.com/refrefef` sin
>   redirrecionar a otra **Urls**

Para definir un documento de error, se usa la directiva [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument). Si se configura una ruta absoluta, **se redireccionará** a la página.

Entonces, simplemente definimos el documento de error en el `.htaccess`:

```python
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que cuando no se usa el protocolo (por ejemplo el "http://"), la URL es reescrita, por lo que no se modifica en la barra del navegador cuando se accede al documento de error. Y si se usa el protocolo, se redirecciona, cambiando la dirección que ve el usuario en el navegador.

Y luego, sólo por un tema de hacer todo completo y generar el código de error para los robots, en `404.php`, agregamos al principio:

```php
<?php
    http_response_code(404);
?>
```

Comment: funciona muy bien aquel mecanismo solo me gustaria saber como hacen ciertas páginas que visitan una URL errónea pero permanece en la misma página sin redireccionar a 404.php es decir permanece en la misma página de la URL errónea example.com/sjdbwc pero no es redireccionada a 404.php permanece con la única diferencia que muestra un mensaje personalizado de error 404 pero continua en la misma URL mal escrita example.com/sjdbwc

Comment: @Alex Sin el `"http://"` (agregado en la respuesta)

Answer (score 0):

muy ligada a como tengas hecha la aplicación. Sólo te puedo dar ideas sobre algunas cosas que tengo hechas:

1. Páginas que son generadas según ciertos parámetros, que si no están en la url (son partes de esta), redirigen a páginas de error, creadas al efecto.
2. Sistemas de routing, con un listado de urls, si no se encuentran en el listado, tanto las URLs como los verbos HTTP para esas URL hay acciones por defecto, como cargar la principal mostrando un mensaje  o una 404.
3. La forma más fácil, si el sitio no es muy grande y no cambia mucho, es tener una lista blanca de urls en un fichero, te sirve cualquier fichero de texto plano. Al procesar una URL se mira si esta en la lista, sino se hace lo que toque.
4. Listado de URLs en una BD. Es como lo anterior, solo que si se están generando muchas páginas dinámicamente, se generan al tiempo nuevas URLs que se almacenan, si no se encuentra, se cargan las de error.
5. Sistemas híbridos. Últimamente estoy integrando los puntos 2 y 4, un sistema de routing para lo que yo hago y otro de almacenamiendo en BD que lo extiende para contenidos generados por usuarios.

Se basan todos un poco en tener rutas predefinidas o ir creándolas para que encajen en ciertos "límites", más que nada por una tema de seguridad, dar acceso a URLs determinadas es interesante.

No se si te sirva de algo. Un saludo.